# extract and read grib2 files from url with octave

Tags: url, extract, octave

how can we extract and read grib2 files from url with octave?

url like this: https://dd.meteo.gc.ca/model_gem_regional/10km/grib2/06/003/

thank you

Comment: What hav e you tried?

Comment: @mab from a quick look, I don't think you'll have much luck opening grib2 files on octave directly. You're probably better off finding an application to convert grib2 files to better-known formats, and open those instead. e.g. you could try https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json, and then load the json in octave using the `fromJSON` function from the `io` package.

Comment: I can confirm that the wgrib2 tool mentioned [here](https://metclim.ucd.ie/2017/04/dealing-with-grib2-data/) works well. A command such as `wgrib2 CMC_reg_APCP_SFC_0_ps10km_2020121406_P003.grib2 -spread output.csv` will produce a nice csv file you can load into octave with `csvread` or `csv2cell`.